# Constraint To Prevent Adding Value Which Exists In Another Table

Tags: sql, database-design

I would like to add a constraint which prevents adding a value to a column if the value exists in the primary key column of another table.  Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

**Table: MasterParts**

MasterPartNumber (Primary Key)
Description
....

**Table: AlternateParts**

MasterPartNumber (Composite Primary Key, Foreign Key to MasterParts.MasterPartNumber)
AlternatePartNumber (Composite Primary Key)

Problem - Alternate part numbers for each master part number must not themselves exist in the master parts table.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is an example:

**MasterParts**

```
MasterPartNumber    Decription         MinLevel     MaxLevel    ReOderLevel
010-00820-50        Garmin GTN™ 750    1            5           2
```

**AlternateParts**

```
       
MasterPartNumber    AlternatePartNumber         
010-00820-50        0100082050          
010-00820-50        GTN750
```

Comment: Sounds suspicious. Would you like to share the original need, and we may suggest other directions?

Comment: I am suspicious too.  If your database is still in design phase, see [this post](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/02/false-patterns-such-as-reverse-foreign.html) about why a redesign may be in order.  If x can have y only without z, there is probably some commonality between y and z that should land them in the same table.

Comment: See my edit, let me know if you are still suspicious but I think it is okay.

Comment: @Reafidy Yes, still suspicious.  George's answer and gidireich's edited answer would both enforce this requirement more transparently than a check constraint.

Comment: @Reafidy Your comment on George's answer clarifies this a little further.  Since the alternates are not actually 'parts', only numbers, separate tables may be correct after all.  In that case, go with the check constraint.

Comment: Reafidy, if you want us to comment further on the design, you need to explain "Alternate part numbers for each master part number must not themselves exist in the master parts table".

What I wrote in my answer  'If you think of master and alternate parts, as totally different things, there is no reason why you may want "Alternate part numbers for each master part number must not themselves exist in the master parts table". Otherwise, you have a common notion of "parts" be it master or alternate. This means they need to be in the same table, and column.'

Comment: gidireich, have you read all my comments to your answer below?  Do you still need further explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only way I could think of solving this would be writing a checking function(not sure what language you are working with), or trying to play around with table relationships to ensure that it's unique

Comment: I agree, create a function that takes the value as a parameter and returns 1 if the value exists, then make the CHECK constraint `fn(value) <> 1`

Comment: VB.NET, I'm not sure what you mean by "playing around with table relationships".

Comment: databases such as MySQL have relationships(just like MSAccess and many others) that link tables, its not that easy to understand, but when you master it, it makes databases a lot easier to handle http://www.techrepublic.com/article/relational-databases-defining-relationships-between-database-tables/5034792

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my misleading comment.  I'm aware of what relationships are and how they work, I'm not sure how "playing around with them" helps me.

Comment: Would really need to see what the tables look like to be able to help more, but I'd suggest just adding a custom function to check if the record is in other table and just return true or false, that way you can also handle output(e.g. telling the user that it already exists, etc)

Comment: See my edit to the original post, I added what the tables look like.

Answer (score 2):

Why not have a single "part" table with an "is master part" flag and then have an "alternate parts" table that maps a "master" part to one or more "alternate" parts?

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to do that because the master part table has a lot of attributes.  An alternate part number does not have these attributes as it is strictly an alternate part number to a specific master part number.  Listing each alternate part in the master part table will add too much redundant data.

Comment: So split the master part table into 2 - one the common colums for master part and alternate part - and another table with the same PK for the master part details

Comment: @Mark - Fine, but how are you suggesting I map alternates to masters?

Comment: @Reafidy: not an SQL expert by any means, but I was just thinking a table with (MasterPartNumber, AlternatePartNumber). If it's impossible for one part to be an alternate part for more than one master part then I'd put a primary key on MasterPartNumber.

Comment: as @George says - and for a real number AlternatePartNumber = MasterPartNumber

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it without procedural code. I've deliberately left out `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE CASCADE`, but in production I'd might use both. (But I'd severely limit who's allowed to update and delete part numbers.)

```
-- New tables
create table part_numbers (
  pn varchar(50) primary key,
  pn_type char(1) not null check (pn_type in ('m', 'a')),
  unique (pn, pn_type)
);

create table part_numbers_master (
  pn varchar(50) primary key,
  pn_type char(1) not null default 'm' check (pn_type = 'm'),
  description varchar(100) not null,
  foreign key (pn, pn_type) references part_numbers (pn, pn_type)
);

create table part_numbers_alternate (
  pn varchar(50) primary key,
  pn_type char(1) not null default 'a' check (pn_type = 'a'),
  foreign key (pn, pn_type) references part_numbers (pn, pn_type)
);

-- Now, your tables.
create table masterparts (
  master_part_number varchar(50) primary key references part_numbers_master,
  min_level integer not null default 0 check (min_level >= 0),
  max_level integer not null default 0 check (max_level >= min_level),
  reorder_level integer not null default 0 
    check ((reorder_level < max_level) and (reorder_level >= min_level))
);

create table alternateparts (
  master_part_number varchar(50) not null references part_numbers_master (pn),
  alternate_part_number varchar(50) not null references part_numbers_alternate (pn),
  primary key (master_part_number, alternate_part_number)
);

-- Some test data
insert into part_numbers values
('010-00820-50', 'm'),
('0100082050', 'a'),
('GTN750', 'a');

insert into part_numbers_master values
('010-00820-50', 'm', 'Garmin GTN™ 750');

insert into part_numbers_alternate (pn) values
('0100082050'),
('GTN750');

insert into masterparts values 
('010-00820-50', 1, 5, 2);

insert into alternateparts values
('010-00820-50', '0100082050'),
('010-00820-50', 'GTN750');
```

In practice, I'd build updatable views for master parts and for alternate parts, and I'd limit client access to the views. The updatable views would be responsible for managing inserts, updates, and deletes.  (Depending on your company's policies, you might use stored procedures instead of updatable views.)

Comment: Interesting way of doing it - its very tidy, thanks a lot for your effort. Considering there may be  a lot of parts, my only concern is the extra overhead in listing all the part numbers twice and the extra columns designating master or alternate.

Comment: It's pretty easy to write some scripts to generate 10 million part numbers and aliases for testing. That's what I'd do if I were in your shoes.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is perfect.

But SQL isn't very helpful when you try to implement such a design.  There is no declarative way in SQL to enforce your business rule.  You'll have to write two triggers, one for inserts into masterparts, checking the new masterpart identifier doesn't yet exist as an alias, and the other one for inserts of aliases checking that the new alias identifier doesn't yet identiy a masterpart.

Or you can do this in the application, which is worse than triggers, from the data integrity point of view.

(If you want to read up on how to enforce constraints of arbitrary complexity within an SQL engine, best coverage I have seen of the topic is in the book "Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals")

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at that book, I think its a toss-up between this and using a check constraint with a function. I'm leaning towards the function but is there any advantage in using triggers?

Comment: I'm not certain about CHECK constraints.  I tend to think of them as things that cannot reference database tables (i.e. the only stuff they can reference is attribute values of the row being inserted).  I might be wrong.  But even if I am, you still have the phenomenon that you have a single business rule, but you need two distinct declarations in two distinct places to enforce it.  That's not desirable by any standard.

Comment: Thanks, what I have done is placed a unique key on column AlternatePartNumber in table alternate parts.  This takes care of checking the alternate does not already exists for another masterpart. I also have a check constraint which uses a function to prevent adding a alternate which is already identified as a master in the master parts table.  I understand what you are saying about the distinct declarations in two distinct places though, I will look further into triggers.  Here is the check constraint: ([Inventory].[CheckAlternatePartIsNotMasterPart]([AlternatePartNumber])=(0))

Answer (score 0):

Apart that it sounds like a possibly poor design,

You in essence want values spanning two columns in different tables, to be unique.

In order to utilize DBs native capability to check for uniqueness, you can create a 3rd, helper column, which will contain a copy of all the values inside the wanted two columns. And that column will have uniqueness constraint. So for each new value added to one of your target columns, you need to add the same value to the helper column. In order for this to be an inner DB constraint, you can add this by a trigger.

And again, needing to do the above, sounds like an evidence for a poor design.

--

Edit:
Regarding your edit:

You say " Alternate part numbers for each master part number must not themselves exist in the master parts table."
This itself is a design decision, which you don't explain. 
I don't know enough about the domain of your problem, but:
If you think of master and alternate parts, as totally different things, there is no reason why you may want "Alternate part numbers for each master part number must not themselves exist in the master parts table". Otherwise, you have a common notion of "parts" be it master or alternate. This means they need to be in the same table, and column.

If the second is true, you need something like this:

table "parts"
columns:

id - pk

is_master - boolean (assuming a part can not be master and alternate at the same time)

description - text

This tables role is to list and describe the parts.

Then you have several ways to denote which part is alternate to which. It depends on whether a part can be alternate to more than one part. And it sounds that anyway one master part can have several alternates. 
You can do it in the same table, or create another one.

If same: add column: alternate_to, which will be null for master parts, and will have a foreign key into the id column of the same table.

Otherwise create a table, say "alternatives" with: master_id, alternate_id both referencing with a foreign key to the parts table.
(The first above assumes that a part cannot be alternate to more than one other part. If this is not true, the second will work anyway)

Comment: Thanks, I edited my original post to be more clear.  I think the idea of the function by @Saulius may be better, using a helper column which appears to mean listing the entire Part Number column twice, seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: Masterparts and alternate parts are not the same at all.  An alternate part number is specifically another part number for a specific master part number.  See my second edit.  Alternate part numbers will not have all the attributes of a master part.  I did not add this information or explain it to start with because I wanted to keep the question simple.  However as a lot of helpers have suspected a design flaw I have tried to explain the situation in more detail.

Comment: Also, alternate part numbers must be unique.  An alternate can not be an alternate to multiple master parts.